# display one of two fields in every row

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

I have table like:

```
+------+-----+
| name | nick|
+------+-----+
| yosi | Y   |
| adam | NULL|
+------+-----+
```

I need output of one column, of **nick** if **nick is not null**, or of **name** if **nick is null**.
like this:

```
+------+
|result|
+------+
| Y    |
| adam |
+------+
```

Is there a query for that ?

Comment: It does not look like your questio make sense. Can you rephrase it?... I figured it out. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ISNULL(nick, name) as result FROM table
```

for Access and SQL server

Comment: Don't post SQL for an Access question that doesn't run in Access. And in particular, don't claim explicitly that it WILL work in Access -- -1

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT IFNULL(nick, name) as result FROM table
```

This will work in MySQL. See documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

Comment: +1 guess it would have gotten more buzz with a link to documentation. ;)

Answer (score 1):

In Access, I use the nz() function for that, eg:

```
SELECT nz(nick, name) as result FROM table
```